# What is the maximum size for a document in Lotus Notes 6.5.1?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I am working in Lotus Notes 6.5.1. I am facing problem with 32K error.

Problem :-

I am having database in 6.5.1 server. I am having a lot of documents that exceeds 32000 bytes.Whenever I open and save the mentioned size documents after that I can not open the document. It is throwing 32k Error. But if the document size is less than 32000 bytes then I can open the document after saving it. I can restrict the document document size. As of my knowledge there is no limitation for document length.

http://www.thenorth.com/northern.nsf/ac567d6535ab069785256a00004d66dc/4100857248b8b82185256d350058f7e4!OpenDocument

Just I want to know, why is this happening. Because of this issue, My scheduled agents are not running. GetNextDocument is not fetching the next document.

One Information:-  My database disk space is 96% being used.

Is the document size related to the above information? or Notes Document having any specific features?

Comment: How were the documents created? As @dmytro mentions below, when you save the document, it is becoming a summary field, which is why it throws the error only after it has been saved.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have hit the 32K limit for a single (Summary) field:

> Notes/Domino 6.x and later have the following limits regarding Summary
>   fields: 32k per field, 64k per document.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21087474 for more info and for workarounds.

Comment: Yes I agree with your point. Problem is, if some document's size is more than 32Kb but less than 62Kb, I can open that document. But I just press the ctrl+s after opening and editing it, except that I do nothing. Once I press the save button from that second I could not open the document and I received the 32k error.

Comment: It's a field size limitation, not a document size limitation.

Comment: Surely Problem is not from any other computed fields. Problem is in my Rich Text Field. Because If I click the attachment button from tool bar and select 5mb or 10 mb of files. It does not throw the 32K error. But If I take the print screen and paste it into my rich Text field. Now I am getting error. Small size of images do nothing. Hope you cleared... Is their any restriction for pasting the things in RCT.

Comment: rich text fields can't be a problem, their limit is 1 Gb as far as I remember. I would recommend you to cut half a form and repeat steps, then cut another half of form and verfiy etc, at the end u will find a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was already given to subject. Here only solution for such problem.

You can avoid problem with those limits if you set flag Summary to false.

```
dim item as notesitem
set item = doc.getFirstItem('itemname')
item.IsSummary = false
call doc.save(true, false)
```

and u 'do not do nothing' when you press Ctrl+s - u actually refresh document and then save it. I guess you have some computed fields on form that are refreshed and their size go up.